# JS Filter array to remove duplicate values based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array containing duplicate elemnets

```
let myArray=[
     {role: "role-1", deviceId: ""},
     {role: "role-2", deviceId: "d-2"},
     {role: "role-3", deviceId: "d-3"},
     {role: "role-1", deviceId: "d-1"},
     {role: "role-2", deviceId: ""},
     {role: "role-4", deviceId: ""}
     {role: "role-5", deviceId: ""}
]
```

I want to remove the duplicate roles and have array which contains roles without empty("") deviceIds and if deviceId is empty keep only one role without duplicates in this way

```
myArray=[
         {role: "role-1", deviceId: "d-1"},
         {role: "role-2", deviceId: "d-2"},
         {role: "role-3", deviceId: "d-3"}
         {role: "role-4", deviceId: ""}
         {role: "role-5", deviceId: ""}

 ]
```

I have written the function in this way

```
function dedupeByKey(arr, key) {
  const temp = arr.map(el => el[key]);
  return arr.filter((el, i) =>
    temp.indexOf(el[key]) === i
  );
}

console.log(dedupeByKey(myArray, 'role'));
```

But in the result, its not checking to give priority for deviceId with values and role with empty deviceId is getting added. How to fix this?

Comment: Why `role-2` have `deviceId: "d-21"`?

Comment: @omri_saadon My bad. I edited

Comment: Also, why you have `role-3` twice in the result while at the beginning you had one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce with default to object, and if you need, you can convert it to array at the end.

```js
let myArray = [
     {role: "role-1", deviceId: ""},
     {role: "role-2", deviceId: "d-2"},
     {role: "role-3", deviceId: "d-3"},
     {role: "role-1", deviceId: "d-1"},
     {role: "role-2", deviceId: ""},
     {role: "role-4", deviceId: ""},
     {role: "role-5", deviceId: ""}
]

const res = myArray.reduce((agg, itr) => {
  if (agg[itr.role]) return agg // if deviceId already exist, skip this iteration
  agg[itr.role] = itr.deviceId  // if deviceId not exist, Add it
  return agg
}, {})

let make_array = Object.keys(res).map(key => { return { role: key, deviceId: res[key] }})

console.log(make_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map the unique role to an object and reduce the object to an array as following code snippet

```js
let myArray = [
     {role: "role-1", deviceId: ""},
     {role: "role-2", deviceId: "d-2"},
     {role: "role-3", deviceId: "d-3"},
     {role: "role-1", deviceId: "d-1"},
     {role: "role-2", deviceId: ""},
     {role: "role-4", deviceId: ""},
     {role: "role-5", deviceId: ""}
];

var uniqueObj = myArray.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  var deviceId = acc[item.role] && acc[item.role].deviceId || item.deviceId;
  acc[item.role] = item;
  acc[item.role].deviceId = deviceId;
  return acc;
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(uniqueObj).reduce(function(acc2, item) {
  acc2.push(uniqueObj[item]);
  return acc2;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a filter an look ahead in the array for duplicates to decide to filter the index or keep it

```js
const myArray= [
     {role: "role-1", deviceId: ""},
     {role: "role-2", deviceId: ""},
     {role: "role-3", deviceId: "d-3"},
     {role: "role-1", deviceId: "d-1"},
     {role: "role-2", deviceId: ""},
     {role: "role-4", deviceId: ""},
     {role: "role-5", deviceId: ""}
]
  
const cleanArray = myArray.filter( (item,index,array) => {
  if ( item.deviceId === "") {
    // filter it out when the same role is found in the array and the index isn't the same as current item you are looking at 
    return !array.some((i,idx) => i.role === item.role && idx > index  )
  }
  return true 
})

// for presentation: sort the array
const sortedArray = cleanArray.sort( (curr, next) => curr.role >  next.role? 1:-1);

console.log(sortedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd group by `role`, then take the first with an `deviceId`:

```
  function groupBy(array, key) {
    const result = { };
    for(const el of array) {
      if(!result[ el[key] ]) result[ el[key] ] = [];
       result[ el[key] ].push(el);
   }
  return result;
}

const result = [];
const grouped = groupBy(myArray, "role");
for(const group of Object.values(grouped)) {
  result.push(group.find(it => it.deviceId) || group[0]);
}
```